# Set does not work in for loop scripting windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to set IP Address to a variable but my code isn't working.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion enableextensions

SET IP=
for /f " tokens=14 delims= " %%i in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"') do  SET /P IP = %%i
call :foo  

:foo
SET _AA = IP   
echo _AA
```

Comment: Really helps if you read the help and documentation for the command you are trying to use? The set command is not that difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve your goal:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "IP="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('IPConfig^|Find "IPv4"') Do Set "IP=%%A"
If Not Defined IP GoTo :EOF
Set "IP=%IP:*: =%"
Echo( Local variable %%IP%% resolves to %IP%
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are significant on both sides of the `=` in a `set`

remove the spaces.

In order to reference the *contents* of a variable `var` you need to use `%var%`

Batch simply continues line-by-line until it reaches a `goto` or end-of-file. It has no concept of "procedures." Having executed your `for`, it will continue and once again execute the `set` and `echo`. You need a line

```
goto :eof
```

before the label `:foo`. This instruction goes to end-of-file (the colon in this case is *required*)

Comment: @Mert, so you are saying you would rather have someone give you the fish then learn to fish.